# Can't Create pandas DataFrame in python (Wrong Shape)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create the following data frame

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data = percentage_default, columns = 
df['purpose'].unique())
```

The variables I'm using are as follows

```
percentage_default = [0.15238817285822592,
0.11568938193343899,
0.16602316602316602,
0.17011128775834658,
0.2778675282714055,
0.11212814645308924,
0.20116618075801748]

df['purpose'].unique = array(['debt_consolidation', 'credit_card', 'all_other',
   'home_improvement', 'small_business', 'major_purchase',
   'educational'], dtype=object)
```

When I try to create this data frame I get the following error:

```
Shape of passed values is (1, 7), indices imply (7, 7)
```

To me it seemed like the shape of the values and idices were the same. Could someone explain what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a dataframe from a list. Calling `pd.DataFrame(your_list)` where your_list is a simple homogenous list will create a single row for every element in that list. For your input:

```
percentage_default = [0.15238817285822592,
                      0.11568938193343899,
                      0.16602316602316602,
                      0.17011128775834658,
                      0.2778675282714055,
                      0.11212814645308924,
                      0.20116618075801748]
```

pandas will create a dataframe like this:

```
Column
0.15238817285822592
0.11568938193343899
0.16602316602316602
0.17011128775834658
0.2778675282714055
0.11212814645308924
0.20116618075801748
```

Because of this, your dataframe only has one column. You're trying to pass multiple column names, which is confusing pandas.

If you wish to create a dataframe from a list with multiple columns, you need to nest more lists or tuples inside your original list. Each nested tuple/list will become a row in the dataframe, and each element in the nested tuple/list will become a new column. See this:

```
percentage_default = [(0.15238817285822592,
                       0.11568938193343899,
                       0.16602316602316602,
                       0.17011128775834658,
                       0.2778675282714055,
                       0.11212814645308924,
                       0.20116618075801748)] # nested tuple
```

We have one nested tuple in this list, so our dataframe will have 1 row with n columns, where n is the number of elements in the nested tuple (7). We can then pass your 7 column names:

```
percentage_default = [(0.15238817285822592,
                       0.11568938193343899,
                       0.16602316602316602,
                       0.17011128775834658,
                       0.2778675282714055,
                       0.11212814645308924,
                       0.20116618075801748)]

col_names = ['debt_consolidation', 'credit_card', 'all_other',
             'home_improvement', 'small_business', 'major_purchase',
             'educational']

new_df = pd.DataFrame(percentage_default, columns = col_names)
print(new_df)


    debt_consolidation  credit_card  all_other  home_improvement  \
0            0.152388     0.115689   0.166023          0.170111   

   small_business  major_purchase  educational  
0        0.277868        0.112128     0.201166
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite your data in a next way:

```
percentage_default = {
    'debt_consolidation': 0.15238817285822592,
    'credit_card': 0.11568938193343899,
    ...
}
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html